# Weblogic undeploy throws TimeoutException

Tags: deployment, timeout, weblogic

I use WebLogic 12.2.1.3.0 and recently it started to show a strange behavior.

After the virtual machine restart I install a new deployment and everything is ok. But when I try to delete this app, it thinks 5-6 minutes and after that shows the following messages:

- An error occurred during activation of changes, please see the log for details.
- weblogic.utils.concurrent.TimeoutException
- Selected deployments were deleted.

[Undeployment timeoutexception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MiMDh.png)

Deployments configuration tab is now empty and "There are no items to display". But when I go to Monitoring -> EJBs -> Stateless, I can see that beans were not deleted. And some of them are even being in use.

[Monitoring - EJBs - Stateless](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zB7Hm.png)

But all beans should be deleted after deleting the deployed app. I can't install the new deployment due to such behavior, and it becomes possible only after the virtual machine restart.

That's what AdminServer log shows after undeploying attempt:

```
####<Apr 26, 2019 11:24:06,471 AM MSK> <Error> <Console> <savet-test> <AdminServer> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '8' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <weblogic> <> <70b79d54-91ef-4f48-bfc6-4dbcdeebc8ac-00000028> <1556267046471> <[severity-value: 8] [rid: 0] [partition-id: 0] [partition-name: DOMAIN] > <BEA-240003> <Administration Console encountered the following error: weblogic.utils.concurrent.TimeoutException
    at weblogic.management.provider.internal.ActivateQueue$ActivateTaskImplWithTimeout.timeout(ActivateQueue.java:535)
    at weblogic.management.provider.internal.ActivateQueue.checkTimeout(ActivateQueue.java:252)
    at weblogic.management.provider.internal.ActivateQueue.checkTimeout(ActivateQueue.java:238)
    at weblogic.management.provider.internal.ActivateQueue.access$100(ActivateQueue.java:30)
    at weblogic.management.provider.internal.ActivateQueue$TaskWithTimeout$1.timerExpired(ActivateQueue.java:295)
    at weblogic.timers.internal.TimerImpl.run(TimerImpl.java:301)
    at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:678)
    at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager._runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:352)
    at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager.runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:337)
    at weblogic.work.LivePartitionUtility.doRunWorkUnderContext(LivePartitionUtility.java:57)
    at weblogic.work.PartitionUtility.runWorkUnderContext(PartitionUtility.java:41)
    at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.runWorkUnderContext(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:652)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:420)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:360)
> 
####<Apr 26, 2019 11:24:06,480 AM MSK> <Warning> <netuix> <savet-test> <AdminServer> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '8' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <weblogic> <> <70b79d54-91ef-4f48-bfc6-4dbcdeebc8ac-00000028> <1556267046480> <[severity-value: 16] [rid: 0] [partition-id: 0] [partition-name: DOMAIN] > <BEA-423420> <Redirect is executed in begin or refresh action. Redirect url is /console/console.portal?_nfpb=true&_pageLabel=AppDeploymentsControlPage.> 
####<Apr 26, 2019 11:24:37,526 AM MSK> <Warning> <Socket> <savet-test> <AdminServer> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '1' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <70b79d54-91ef-4f48-bfc6-4dbcdeebc8ac-0000002e> <1556267077526> <[severity-value: 16] [rid: 0] [partition-id: 0] [partition-name: DOMAIN] > <BEA-000449> <Closing the socket, as no data read from it on 10.220.133.19:55,301 during the configured idle timeout of 5 seconds.> 
####<Apr 26, 2019 11:24:47,525 AM MSK> <Warning> <Socket> <savet-test> <AdminServer> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '8' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <70b79d54-91ef-4f48-bfc6-4dbcdeebc8ac-0000002f> <1556267087525> <[severity-value: 16] [rid: 0] [partition-id: 0] [partition-name: DOMAIN] > <BEA-000449> <Closing the socket, as no data read from it on 10.220.133.19:55,303 during the configured idle timeout of 5 seconds.> 
####<Apr 26, 2019 11:25:18,155 AM MSK> <Info> <WorkManager> <savet-test> <AdminServer> <Timer-2> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <70b79d54-91ef-4f48-bfc6-4dbcdeebc8ac-0000000a> <1556267118155> <[severity-value: 64] [rid: 0] [partition-id: 0] [partition-name: DOMAIN] > <BEA-002959> <Self-tuning thread pool contains 4 running threads, 1 idle threads, and 11 standby threads> 
####<Apr 26, 2019 11:25:22,525 AM MSK> <Warning> <Socket> <savet-test> <AdminServer> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '8' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <70b79d54-91ef-4f48-bfc6-4dbcdeebc8ac-00000030> <1556267122525> <[severity-value: 16] [rid: 0] [partition-id: 0] [partition-name: DOMAIN] > <BEA-000449> <Closing the socket, as no data read from it on 10.220.133.19:55,312 during the configured idle timeout of 5 seconds.> 
####<Apr 26, 2019 11:25:27,343 AM MSK> <Info> <Health> <savet-test> <AdminServer> <weblogic.GCMonitor> <<anonymous>> <> <70b79d54-91ef-4f48-bfc6-4dbcdeebc8ac-00000007> <1556267127343> <[severity-value: 64] [rid: 0:1] [partition-id: 0] [partition-name: DOMAIN] > <BEA-310002> <48% of the total memory in the server is free.> 
####<Apr 26, 2019 11:25:29,316 AM MSK> <Info> <Common> <savet-test> <AdminServer> <Thread-27> <weblogic> <> <70b79d54-91ef-4f48-bfc6-4dbcdeebc8ac-0000001e> <1556267129316> <[severity-value: 64] [rid: 0:1] [partition-id: 0] [partition-name: DOMAIN] > <BEA-000628> <Created "1" resources for pool "JDBC Data Source-0", out of which "1" are available and "0" are unavailable.> 
####<Apr 26, 2019 11:25:32,526 AM MSK> <Warning> <Socket> <savet-test> <AdminServer> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '8' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <70b79d54-91ef-4f48-bfc6-4dbcdeebc8ac-00000031> <1556267132526> <[severity-value: 16] [rid: 0] [partition-id: 0] [partition-name: DOMAIN] > <BEA-000449> <Closing the socket, as no data read from it on 10.220.133.19:55,315 during the configured idle timeout of 5 seconds.>
```

Can somebody help me to solve this issue?

Comment: What does the AdminServer log say?

Comment: I have added log output into the description. 
Before the exception, it shows also ThreadDump, I have not included it, because description should be less than 30000 symbols length.